# pause an interval along a chain

Tags: javascript, time, intervals, chain

I know this isn't going to help you understand so I'll break it down.
I have a webpage that has an interval for the time, this time is translated into an hour and that loads a audio file. The problem being that the interval reloads the audio every second and I only want it to interval based on the hour and the clock to work as intended. I have it set up like this.

The basic of it is that I have a page loading stuff based on the time of day and I need a way to edit the time live with some function and change the elements. If there is a better way to do this, I am open to suggestions.

> note: i can not use jquery

```
//interval//
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);
//get the time//
function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
    mod_time(h,m,s)
}
// mod the time //
function mod_time(h,m,s) {
var x = 0;
      if(x == 1){
        var h = h - h + 2
      }
      if(x == 2){
        var h = h - h + 3
      }
      else{
        var h = h;
}
//applying just the hours//
    apply_mod_time(h)
    //displaying the full modded time for debugging//
    var t_str = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    document.getElementById('time2').innerHTML = t_str;
}
//playing sound based on the hour//
function apply_mod_time(h) {
    if (h==1) {
document.getElementById("myAudio").src = "moo.mp3";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another variable that specifies the current hour.  When you execute the interval every second, see if h !== hourVariable.  If they do not match, load the audio file and update the hourVariable to equal h.

Comment: Thats a bit hard to understand, can you give an example?